# Gmail pop3 ssl can't fetch mail server

Tags: ssl, gmail, postfix, pop3, dovecot

Suddenly gmail can't fetch anymore mails from my mail server (postfix, dovecot), with the below message:

```
Unable to establish secure SSL connection to mail.domain.com
Server returned error: "SSL error: Certificate 1 of the best path has an error"
```

We didn't do any recent changes on our server, we are using tls v1.2, on all pop3, imap and smtp,

SMTP is still working okay on gmail,

Any other mail clients like Thunderbird, outlook, mail exchange ..etc are working fine with out server

**Edit:** I checked multiple pop3 ssl validation websites and command line like "`openssl s_client`", and our server passed all

Comment: Have the certificates expired?

Comment: Will expire on Oct 2018

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like since wednesday Google Mail Servers no longer accept intermediate certificates signed using the sha1 hash algorithm.

Running the command `openssl s_client -connect server.example.com:995 -CAfile cacert.pem -showcerts` revealed to me that the mail server was (and still is) providing the sha1 version of the intermediate certificate.

I don't know the name of Intermediate CA that is responsible in your case (It is the 1st one in your case, it was the 2nd in my case) but I'm sure you will find a reissued Intermediate CA Certificate on the CA website. Running `openssl s_client …` with the `-showcerts` parameter should show the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` block under `Certificate chain` where the number is `1` (it begins counting with `0` so it would be the 2nd block). You can copy that BEGIN to END CERTIFICATE block into a .crt or .cer file and open it on Windows to see the details.

*For that particular Intermediate CA in my case the Root CA already had re-issued a sha256 signed version of the same certificate 4 years ago but the server admin put the old sha-1 version into the chain. In my particular case I will just ignore it because I'm no longer actively using that mail account and the admins of that mail server don't seem to be experienced in the SSL/TLS context. (In 2016 it took them 2 months to realize what was wrong and how to fix it even though I had told them in detail, and then they still didn't manage to get it 100% right.)*

Comment: That exactly was my case, i re-issued my sha-1 certificate from my Intermediate CA, and configured it for my mail server, now gmail accepts my ssl connection again :)